# Could not copy the file "Путь к файлу" because it was not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

При попытке собрать решение ловлю вот такую ошибку:

> Could not copy the file "Путь к файлу" because it was not found

И указывает путь к exe моего приложения, которое я компилирую...

В Visual Studio 2017. Пробовал перезагружаться и все такое.

Находил подобный вопрос на enSO, но что-то не помогло... В процессах нету запущенного приложения.

Даже решение с рабочего пк на домашний перекинул и такая же беда...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, нашел проблему:

Поставил себе ранее плагин, который позволяет писать IL-код.

По случайности вместо создания обычного консольного приложения создал проект консольного приложения с поддержкой IL, где добавляется спец. файл куда нужно писать код.

Что бы не пересоздавать проект, я удалил этот файл, думая, что будет все ОК.

В итоге, из-за отсутствия этого файла у меня не строилось решение.

Заглянул в файл проекта, а там были прописаны всякие дополнительные компиляторы и действия, которые были завязаны на этом файле. Вычистил весь мусор и все собралось.